# how might flame retardant feathers work?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, dragons

male [Wyverns](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167897/could-my-wyverns-exist/167926#167926) collect shiny objects in their dens to attract mates it quite common for Wyverns to get into territorial fight. Now Wyverns are capable of breathing fire but they are also covered in feathers (which are quite flammable). In order to combat this Wyverns have developed flame retardant feathers. the question i want know is  how might flame retardant feathers work?

NOTE: magic does not exist in my story

Comment: At some point, the lack of magic kinda disappears under the cumulative effects of handwavium and disbelief-suspension ;-)

Comment: Actually you are mistaken those feathers are actually made of wool ;D

Comment: @user6760 wool and feathers are both made of keratin, so sort of...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the need for your Wyrvens to have hollow bones and other stuff that makes them less frightening-- my opinion is that your best bet would be to have them secrete a flame-retardant oil of some sort that coats their feathers. Birds already secrete oils on their feathers, so it feels natural and believable