# How might a sea wyvern adapt its flame breath?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, evolution, dragons

Sea [Wyverns](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/167897/could-my-wyverns-exist) (name not final) nest on small, rocky islands scattered throughout the sea and primarily catch fish going somewhat below the water. Basically, wyverns ingest a piezoelectric crystal which they store, and when they eject a flammable liquid which they store in a gland, they squeeze the crystal, igniting it. Now I was wondering - how might a sea wyvern adapt its flame breath to its life style? Would it just use it to cook the fish it catches? Or could it modify it to help catch fish and if so how?

NOTE: magic does not exist in my story

Comment: Changed the word "incest" to "ingest" assuming that's what you meant.

Comment: @Zxyrra it was thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Night Fishing**

[image: Issei Fisherman 1948]

In the Hawaiian islands there’s an ancient tradition of night fishing using torches. Many marine species are attracted to light, especially things like squid that rise from the abyss at night to feed.

So your Sea Wyverns use the fire to attract fish. They spray the fire over the surface of the water, and it lingers for a few seconds before going out. This is enough for the fish to be interested and the Wyvern then snatches them.